# Resolving an import to two different modules depending on build

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have two modules: `mymodule-real` and `mymodule-dummy`.

I want webpack to resolve these modules like this, depending on a Webpack environment variable:

```
mymodule -> mymodule-real
or
mymodule -> mymodule-dummy
```

So, I want two have two different 'development' builds: one with the real module, and another with a dummy module that simulates its behavior.

**My success so far:**

I am able to do this:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/mymodule/, function(resource) {
      resource.request = 'mymodule-' + (USE_DUMMY ? 'dummy' : 'real');
    })
  ]
```

But I have a problem: I am writing an Electron app, an I want them to be external, resolved from `/node_modules/`. This plugin does not work if I list these modules in `externals` config section.

Can I redirect imports of *external* modules using Webpack?

Comment: You can split your webpack configuration. And depending on your needs load one of them. webpack-merge can help you. Also, see https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/ Let me know if you're looking something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an [answer from @sokra](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8608#issuecomment-453068285) at Github:

> Yes it's the NormalModuleReplacementPlugin not the
>   ExternalModuleReplacementPlugin.
>
> You may want to do this:
>
> ```
>   externals: (context, request, callback) => {
>     if(/mymodule/.test(request) {
>       return callback(null, USE_DUMMY ? 'mymodule-dummy' : 'mymodule-real'
>     }
>     callback();
>   }
> ```
>
> or this if you don't really need a regexp:
>
> ```
> externals: {
>   mymodule: USE_DUMMY ? 'mymodule-dummy' : 'mymodule-real'
> }
> ```